# How to transfer a Flurry app from one user to another?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

Is it possible to transfer a Flurry app from one user to another user?

Comment: Are you find any way to transfer the flurry app? If yes then I am also have the same question.

Comment: No, so far there is no way to transfer it.